# Javascript ordered array match with closest fallback

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I've got a problem I'm trying to solve that I haven't quite been able to wrap my head around. If someone could point me in the right direction here, I'd appreciate it.

Basically, I'm comparing two ordered arrays in javascript. I have an index array and an array to match to. If all elements in the arrays match in order, I want to return a match. But, I also want to return the closest partial match. For instance

If my index array is

```
var index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

and the array I'm comparing is

```
var compare = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

obviously the should match. But these should all match as well:

```
var compare = ['A']
var compare = ['A', 'B']
var compare = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

These should not match:

```
var compare = ['B']; //doesn't start with 'A'
var compare = ['B', 'C'];  //doesn't start with 'A'
var compare = ['B', 'A']; //not in correct order
```

The arrays will always be in the same order and the order must match in order to evaluate to true.

Basically, I'm trying to return most exact match that I can, but provide the closest fallback if that match doesn't exist. Does anybody know what I'm saying? Any help people could provide would be much appreciated

Comment: You could filter the matches and sort the result by size (biggest first), the first value in the sorted array will be the best match.

Comment: You are missing some fringe cases what about ABCE... Does it match ABCD?

Comment: @NunoSousa, yes, I suppose that would match, too.

Comment: What about `ABEC`? Should that match?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.prototype.every` and have the callback return `true` if the entries at the index for the two arrays match **or** if the index array has an entry for that index but the `compare` array doesn't:

```
const flag = index.every((entry, n) => compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n]);
```

or in ES5:

```
var flag = index.every(function(entry, n) {
    return compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n];
});
```

Live example (ES2015+):

```js
function test(index, compare, expect) {
    const flag = index.every((entry, n) => compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n]);
    console.log(index.join(","), compare.join(","), ":", flag, "=>", !flag === !expect ? "Good" : "ERROR");
}

const index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
test(index, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], true);
test(index, ['A'], true);
test(index, ['A', 'B'], true);
test(index, ['A', 'B', 'C'], true);
test(index, ['B'], false); //doesn't start with 'A'
test(index, ['B', 'C'], false);  //doesn't start with 'A'
test(index, ['B', 'A'], false); //not in correct order
```

If as [Titus suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043609/javascript-ordered-array-match-with-closest-fallback/54043671#comment94922817_54043671) you have an array of arrays and want to find the *best* match, just loop through them and remember the longest one that matches:

```
let match = null;
for (const compare of arrayOfArraysToCompare) {
    // No need to compare ones that are shorter than a known match...
    if (!match || compare.length > match.length) {
        const flag = index.every((entry, n) => compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n]);
        if (flag && (!match || match.length < compare.length)) {
            match = compare;
        }
    }
}
```

or in ES5

```
var match = null;
arrayOfArraysToCompare.forEach(function(compare) {
    // No need to compare ones that are shorter than a known match...
    if (!match || compare.length > match.length) {
        var flag = index.every((entry, n) => compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n]);
        if (flag && (!match || match.length < compare.length)) {
            match = compare;
        }
    }
});
```

Live example (ES2015+):

```js
const index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const arrayOfArraysToCompare = [
  ['A'],          // Match, but not longest match
  ['A', 'B'],     // *** Longest match
  ['B', 'C', 'D'] // Longer, but not a match
];

let match = null;
for (const compare of arrayOfArraysToCompare) {
    // No need to compare ones that are shorter than a known match...
    if (!match || compare.length > match.length) {
        const flag = index.every((entry, n) => compare.length <= n || compare[n] === index[n]);
        if (flag && (!match || match.length < compare.length)) {
            match = compare;
        }
    }
}
console.log(match);
```

Comment: From the description it seems that the OP has multiple arrays and whats to find the best match.

Comment: @Titus - Updated to cover that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
var compare = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

function getMatches(array1, array2){
    var matches = [];
    array1.forEach((element, index) => {
        if(element == array2[index])
            matches.push(element);
        else
            return matches;
    });
    return matches;
}

getMatches(index, compare);
```